# Trying to play sounds on keydown with Howler - The AudioContext was not allowed to start error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, howler.js

I'm trying to build a drum-pad app and it's mostly done, except for an issue I'm facing with keydown. I have it set up that when you press certain keys, a certain text is displayed and a certain sound should be played. This works perfectly with mouse clicks, but when I try to use keyboard buttons, it only displays the text, and gives me this error:

The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. @howler.js:2500

I am using useSound hook that has Howler as a dependency, and there might be an issue with that, but I'm not sure. Here's the link to the docs: https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound

Here's a codesandbox build: https://codesandbox.io/s/drum-pad-jc9b5?file=/src/drumPad.css

Here's the full code:

```
      useEffect(() =>{document.addEventListener("keydown", key)}, []
  )
  function key(e) {
    // This runs the playThis() function when the desired keys are pressed, but the sound doesn't play. 
    let i = 0  
    let keycodes = drumBank.map(function(y, x){
        if (y.keyTrigger === e.key) {
          i = x
          playThis(i)
          
        }})
  } 

  const [powerOn, setPowerOn] = useState(true)
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [Sound0] = useSound(drumBank[0].url) 
  const [Sound1] = useSound(drumBank[1].url) 
  const [Sound2] = useSound(drumBank[2].url) 
  const [Sound3] = useSound(drumBank[3].url) 
  const [Sound4] = useSound(drumBank[4].url) 
  const [Sound5] = useSound(drumBank[5].url) 
  const [Sound6] = useSound(drumBank[6].url) 
  const [Sound7] = useSound(drumBank[7].url) 
  const [Sound8] = useSound(drumBank[8].url)
  

  


 function playThis(num) {
  if (powerOn === true) 
         { setText(drumBank[num].id)
          switch(num) {
          case 0: Sound0()
          break;
          case 1: Sound1()
          break;
          case 2: Sound2()
          break;
          case 3: Sound3()
          break;
          case 4: Sound4()
          break;
          case 5: Sound5()
          break;
          case 6: Sound6()
          break;
          case 7: Sound7()
          break;
          case 8: Sound8()
          break;
        }
      }
        else {setText("Power is off")}
      } 


 
return (
    <div id="drum-machine" className="drumpad-container" >
        <h3 id={powerOn ? "drum-power-text-on" : "drum-power-text-off"}>Power: </h3>
        <div id="drum-power-div" onClick={() => setPowerOn(!powerOn)}>
          <div id={powerOn ? "drum-power-button-on" : "drum-power-button-off"}>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="display" className="drumpad-display">
            <p className="drumpad-text">{text}</p>
        </div>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-1" onClick={() => playThis(0)} >Q</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-2" onClick={() => playThis(1)}>W</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-3" onClick={() => playThis(2)}>E</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-4" onClick={() => playThis(3)}>A</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-5" onClick={() => playThis(4)}>S</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-6" onClick={() => playThis(5)}>D</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-7" onClick={() => playThis(6)}>Z</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-8" onClick={() => playThis(7)}>X</button>
        <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-9" onClick={() => playThis(8)}>C</button>
        </div>
)
```

}

The key function somehow bypasses my power function as well and displays the text even when playThis() should be deactivated when the power is off.

If anyone could help me figure out how to make the sounds play on keypresses, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The useSound hook plays the sound normally on keypress if it is put inside a function, and then that function is called instead of the hook itself. So, instead of just putting these in playThis():

```
  const [Sound0] = useSound(drumBank[0].url) 
  const [Sound1] = useSound(drumBank[1].url) 
  const [Sound2] = useSound(drumBank[2].url) 
  const [Sound3] = useSound(drumBank[3].url) 
  const [Sound4] = useSound(drumBank[4].url) 
  const [Sound5] = useSound(drumBank[5].url) 
  const [Sound6] = useSound(drumBank[6].url) 
  const [Sound7] = useSound(drumBank[7].url) 
  const [Sound8] = useSound(drumBank[8].url)
```

I put these consts into their individual functions like this:

```
  const [Sound0] = useSound(drumBank[0].url) 


  const [Sound1] = useSound(drumBank[1].url) 
  const [Sound2] = useSound(drumBank[2].url) 
  const [Sound3] = useSound(drumBank[3].url) 
  const [Sound4] = useSound(drumBank[4].url) 
  const [Sound5] = useSound(drumBank[5].url) 
  const [Sound6] = useSound(drumBank[6].url) 
  const [Sound7] = useSound(drumBank[7].url) 
  const [Sound8] = useSound(drumBank[8].url)
  let audio0 = () => {sound0()}
  let audio1 = () => {sound1()}
  let audio2 = () => {sound2()}
  let audio3 = () => {sound3()}
  let audio4 = () => {sound4()}
  let audio5 = () => {sound5()}
  let audio6 = () => {sound6()}
  let audio7 = () => {sound7()}
  let audio8 = () => {sound8()}
```

and then in my playThis() function I put audio0() instead of sound0(), and then it works. Like this:

```
 function playThis(num) {
  if (powerOn === true) 
         { setText(drumBank[num].id)
          switch(num) {
          case 0: audio0()
          break;
          case 1: audio1()
          break;
          case 2: audio2()
          break;
          case 3: audio3()
          break;
          case 4: audio4()
          break;
          case 5: audio5()
          break;
          case 6: audio6()
          break;
          case 7: audio7()
          break;
          case 8: audio8()
          break;
        }
      }
        else {setText("Power is off")}
      }
```

As for the keypresses bypassing the power button, I just used a useKeyPress add-on and that one works very well.